# Get the value of a field for the latest record in a collection

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a collection rawUnits. I am getting the latest record from this collection using

```
db.getCollection('rawUnits').find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

This gives me the record which has a nested field saleinfo.group.id
I want to get the value for this field how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can `$project` it:

```
db.getCollection('rawUnits').find({}, {'saleinfo.group.id':1}).limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

But it is better to limit your search, if you filter by any field...

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.