# I want to find the last object which i'm posting in my database without any condition but i can't find any method for that

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Data.findOne({}).then((respp)=>console.log(respp, "find one"))

Like  I have this method this is returning First object and if I apply a condition then i can get only matched element but i want every-time when data is submitted the last submitted object I need and then I can use that for my further process

I want to call a specifc function and want to pass the latest object which i need to get from mongodb to that function like that
Data.findOne({ want to get last submitted dobject here }).then((respp)=> addRow(respp))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of a field for the latest record in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72141304/get-the-value-of-a-field-for-the-latest-record-in-a-collection)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need solution using mongoose

Comment: @damianesteban 
// Ok I have a function which is used to add a row into google sprerad sheet directly
// I want to  find the latest document which is submitted in my db and pass that object to that addRow() function so my google sheet can be updated like this 
`app.post("/post", (req,res)=>{
    const data = req.body
    rows.push(data)
    addRow(rows)
`

Comment: // like here the latest object is passed to addRow()  fn but I want to first submit the data into database and then get from database and use it  

    // liek this 
`const dataa = new Data(req.body)
dataa.save().then((resp)=> console.log(resp))`
// here data is saved in db now 
// now i want to get latest object from db to pass it to addRow simple but mongoose findone method only returns the matching id email etc object i don't want to compare anything i just need latest submitted object from the db 
`Data.findOne({}).then((respp)=> addRow(respp))
})`
`

Answer (score 0):

sort data on _id. this provides the latest document in the collection

```
Data.findOne({}).sort({_id:-1}).then((respp)=>console.log(respp, "find one"))
```

Comment: it's giving me last object from database i need the submitted object